# How to Update Parts of a document in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

In scanning the docs I cannot find how to update part of a document.

for example - say the whole document looks like this:

```
{
      "Active": true,
      "Barcode": "123456789",
      "BrandID": "9f3751ef-f14f-464a-bb86-854e99cf14c0",
      "BuyCurrencyOverride": ".37",
      "BuyDiscountAmount": "45.00",
      "ID": "003565a3-4a0d-47d9-befb-0ac642cb8057",
}
```

but I only want to work with part of the document as I don't want to be selecting / updating the whole document in many cases:

```
{
      "Active": false,
      "Barcode": "999999999",
      "BrandID": "9f3751ef-f14f-464a-bb86-854e99cf14c0",
      "ID": "003565a3-4a0d-47d9-befb-0ac642cb8057",
}
```

How can I use `N1QL` to just update those fields?  Upsert completely replaces the whole document and update statement is not that clear.

Thanks

Comment: What update statements have you tried? Should be something like UPDATE x USING KEYS y SET Active = False, Barcode = 9999999,SET ... RETURNING x.*

Comment: So - I'm quite new to Couchbase , and it looks like what I want to do is actually a new feature in 4.5 Beta which is what I am using.  I want to seelect and update part of the document http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/developer-guide/sub-doc-api.html  .  I just haven't been able to put an object into N1QL and get it working ( in the in-built query editor )

Comment: Personally, I haven't used N1QL, but [`UPDATE`](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html) is part of the 4.1 docs

Comment: Thanks, but I think if I have to update each attribute individually - then I may as well stick to SQL server.

Comment: I had a look at this as well http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5-dp/n1ql-enhancements.html - I just can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: You can update as many parts as you want using a single UPDATE statement. The N1QL UPDATE statement is a superset of SQL Server. I am missing what you are missing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on *why* you want to update only part of the document (e.g., are you concerned about network bandwidth?), and how you want to perform the update (e.g., from the web console? from a program using the SDK?).

The 4.5 sub-document API, for which you provided a link in your comment, is a feature only available via the SDK (e.g., from Go or Java programs), and the goal of that feature is to reduce network bandwidth by no transmitting entire documents around. Does your use case include programmatic document modifications via the SDK? If so, then the sub-document API is a good way to go.

Using the "[UPDATE](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html)" statement in N1QL is a good way to change any number of documents that match a pattern for which you can specify a "WHERE" clause. As noted above, it works very similarly to the "UPDATE" statement in SQL. To use your example above, you could change the "Active" field to false in any documents where the BuyDiscountAmount was "45.00":

```
UPDATE my bucket SET Active = false WHERE BuyDiscountAmount = "45.00"
```

When running N1QL UPDATE queries, almost all the network traffic will be between the Query, Index, and Data nodes of your cluster, so a N1QL update does not cause much network traffic into/out-of your cluster.

If you provide more details about your use case, and why you want to update only part of your documents, I could provide more specific advice on the right approach to take.

Comment: Ok great thanks.  Yes I will be using the .Net SDK ( maybe available for .Net ? ) .  I would rather bind a page to a whole document - then just be able to submit that document rather than write updates for each field - yes saving network bandwidth.

Comment: The latest versions of all the SDKs should support the sub-document API, with the exception of PHP (which will be available soon), so you should be able to use it with .Net.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-doc API introduced in Couchbase4.5 is currently not used by N1QL. However, when you use the UPDATE statement to update parts of one or more documents.

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html

Let me know any Qs.
-Prasad

Answer (score 0):

It is simple like sql query.

```
update `Employee` set District='SambalPur' where EmpId="1003"
```

and here is the responce

{

```
    "Employee": {
      "Country": "India",
      "District": "SambalPur",
      "EmpId": "1003",
      "EmpName": "shyam",
      "Location": "New-Delhi"
    }
  }
```